# std::map and id's that keep incrementing

Tags: c++

I'm working on a client and server project.

There's a std::map of all sessions which looks a bit like this:

```
std::map<int, SOCKET> Sessions;
int g_TotalClientCount;
void Server::HandleNewClientConnection(SOCKET clientSocket){
    Sessions.insert(pair<int, SOCKET>(g_TotalClientCount, clientSocket));
    g_TotalClientCount++;
}
/*Something similar on disconnect*/
void Server::KickClient(int clientId){
    SendPacket(...)
    Sessions.erase(clientId);
}
```

Let's say that over time, g_TotalClientCount gets really high and ends up being over MAX_INT(and end up causing bugs/a crash).

Is there any proper way to erase and insert items in the map but also keeping g_TotalClientCount to the actual number of users connected instead of the number of users that connected ?
Using

```
g_TotalClientCount--;
```

would end up causing duplicates.

g_TotalClientCount is only used in the HandleNewClientConnection part.

I know I'll probably never have that being an actual issue, but I'd like to know the proper way to do this.

Comment: Why do you use a map?

Comment: Mostly because I can use map.find(clientId) and map[clientId] to get the SOCKET,

Comment: Use `uint64_t` as the key? 18446744073709551615 sockets should be enough for anybody

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A better fit for your problem would be a [`std::set`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set) (logarithmic complexity) or better yet, a [`std::unordered_set`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_set) (constant-time complexity). You can use the `iterator` returned by the `insert` method as your `clientId`:

C++98:

```
#include <set>

std::set<SOCKET> Sessions;

std::set<SOCKET>::iterator Server::HandleNewClientConnection(SOCKET clientSocket) {
    std::pair<std::unordered_set<SOCKET>::iterator, bool> inserted =
        Sessions.insert(clientSocket);
    if (!inserted.second) {
        // handle the insertion error
    }
    return inserted.first;
}

void Server::KickClient(std::set<SOCKET>::iterator clientId){
    SendPacket(...)
    Sessions.erase(clientId);
}
```

C++11+:

```
#include <unordered_set>

std::unordered_set<SOCKET> Sessions;

auto Server::HandleNewClientConnection(SOCKET clientSocket) {
    auto inserted = Sessions.insert(clientSocket);
    if (!inserted.second) {
        // handle the insertion error
    }
    return inserted.first;
}

void Server::KickClient(std::unordered_set<SOCKET>::iterator clientId){
    SendPacket(...)
    Sessions.erase(clientId);
}
```

C++17:

```
#include <unordered_set>

std::unordered_set<SOCKET> Sessions;

auto Server::HandleNewClientConnection(SOCKET clientSocket) {
    auto [iterator, success] = Sessions.insert(clientSocket);
    if (!success) {
        // handle the insertion error
    }
    return iterator;
}

void Server::KickClient(std::unordered_set<SOCKET>::iterator clientId){
    SendPacket(...)
    Sessions.erase(clientId);
}
```